# When I call the unofficial claude2 model published on the Github website, my output displays HTML format instead of JSON format，what should I do?

Tags: github, cookies

The original link of the webpage is as follows: https://github.com/Nipun1212/Claude_api . After I followed his method to obtain the cookie, the response returned by this model will be displayed in HTML format instead of JSON format, causing subsequent Python files to be unable to complete decoding. What should I do?

I have tried replacing the cookie with a new one and requesting that this model return JSON format, but it still returns HTML format. Is it because the cookie I obtained was incorrect? How can I obtain cookies that can be used?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.